# Google Play Services Missing from Extras folder in SDK Manager

Tags: android, eclipse

So basically I can't find the option to install/download the Google Play Services in the Extras folder of the Android SDK Manager. What could be the possible reasons ?
Meanwhile can somebody provide the link to download the lib from the Web ?

Comment: just update the already installed files listed in the sdk manger. restart the sdk manger, you can find the play service in the tools or extras folder

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and finally figured out a solution that worked for me. Here's what I did:

- Go to Help -> Install New Software.

  - My android environment was already set up, so I picked "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" from the drop down menu
  - Check the top level option - "Developer Tools"
  - Hit the next button and follow the prompts.  It said I already had it installed and this would apply an update
  - Ran the SDK Manager again and it now showed me the Google Play Services option to install

Answer (score 3):

Same problem, there are only 2 items (Android Support Library and Intel Emulator Accelerator) in my Extras folder...
I running Windows 8.1 64bit , so maybe a bug..

Comment: problem solved! Start SDK Manager as admin and update everything you CAN update, restart SDK and see changes.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**
 
Step 1: Update everything you already have installed using the SDK manager
Step 2: Reopen SDK manager, you should see more stuff under extras including Google Play Services.

Comment: Question is different he have asked in Extra folder not look google services

Answer (score 0):

where are you looking for Google Play Services?

After installing it via SDK Manager, you can get it in your SDK folder extras/google/google_play_services

You have to import it first in your IDE and then include in your project as a library project.

Comment: The problem is that I can't install it in SDK Manager. Using it is an entirely different matter

Comment: which revision are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If your at SDK 19 you may not have it show because your SDK is too low, at least it was the case for me. I was offered it among 17 other install recommendations after upgrading to SDK 20, SDK Tools 23.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading new version of adt solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i solved by install  the last SDk update and build tools and the 
google_play_services appear in tools folder to download

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution i got it. please download new version of the android adt bundle and  extract the folder then go to the folder right click the sdk manger and run at administrator and restart your system open eclipse go to sdk manager under extras folder you have google play services finally update it.

Answer (score 0):

Open your SDK Manager and update Android SDK Tools. I had the same problem and this solved.